# DataFrame - how to calculate conditional rolling sum?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with Football data, where each row represents a match. The DataFrame includes the following columns: 'Date', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'Points_HomeTeam', 'Points_AwayTeam'.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'Date'    'HomeTeam'   'AwayTeam'  'Points_HomeTeam' 'Points_AwayTeam'   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2000-08-19 Charlton     Man City          0                 3            |
| 2000-08-19 Chelsea      Arsenal           1                 1            |
| 2000-08-23 Coventry     Man City          3                 0            |
| 2000-08-25 Man City     Liverpool         1                 1            |
| 2000-08-28 Derby        Man City          1                 1            |
| 2000-08-31 Leeds        Chelsea           3                 0            |
| 2000-08-31 Man City     Everton           3                 0            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to include a column that shows the sum of the points of the HomeTeam in its last two away games, i.e. the sum of the value in the column 'Points_AwayTeam' for the previous two instances of rows in which the 'AwayTeam' equals the 'HomeTeam' of the respective current row.

For example, in the following table, the new column for the first occurrence of 'Man City' in the column 'HomeTeam' would have the value '3' (the sum of the values in column 'Points_AwayTeam' for the previous two occurrences of 'Man City' in column 'AwayTeam', i.e. 0 + 3)
Similarly, the new column for the second occurrence of 'Man City' in the column 'HomeTeam' would have the value '1' (1 + 0).
The values for the other rows would be 'NA' as there no other 'HomeTeam' has two occurrences in column 'AwayTeam'.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'Date'    'HomeTeam'   'AwayTeam'  'Points_HomeTeam' 'Points_AwayTeam' 'New Column' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2000-08-19 Charlton     Man City          0                 3          NA           |
| 2000-08-19 Chelsea      Arsenal           1                 1          NA           |
| 2000-08-23 Coventry     Man City          3                 0          NA           |
| 2000-08-25 Man City     Liverpool         1                 1          3            |
| 2000-08-28 Derby        Man City          1                 1          NA           |
| 2000-08-31 Leeds        Chelsea           3                 0          NA           |
| 2000-08-31 Man City     Everton           3                 0          1            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I managed to calculate the sum of the points of the 'HomeTeam' in its last two home games with the following code:

```
f = lambda x: x.rolling(window = rolling_games, min_periods = rolling_games).sum().shift()
df['HomeTeam_HomePoints'] = df.groupby('HomeTeam')['Points_HomeTeam'].apply(f).reset_index(drop = True, level = 0)
```

How can I calculate a rolling sum across rows conditional on the value in a separate column?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you please add some sample data, as well as the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for you comment! I edited the question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
away = df[["Date", "AwayTeam", "Points_AwayTeam"]].copy()

# Create a rolling sum for the away column. 
away["roll_sum"] = away.groupby("AwayTeam")["Points_AwayTeam"].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2).sum())
    
# for every match, we now have to find the last rolling sum 
# of 'away' for the 'home' team. 
# 
# We're going to use merge_asof to do that:
# The first step of this function is to match home-teams on the left
# to away teams on the left. (done via left_by and right_by)
# then, for every date on the left, we're looking for the closest 
# (previous) date on the right (this is done by the 'on' argument). 
res=pd.merge_asof(df, away, on= "Date", left_by="HomeTeam", right_by="AwayTeam", suffixes=["", "_roll"])
res.drop(["AwayTeam_roll", "Points_AwayTeam_roll"], axis=1, inplace = True)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
        Date  HomeTeam   AwayTeam  Points_HomeTeam  Points_AwayTeam  roll_sum
0 2000-08-19  Charlton   Man-City                0                3       NaN
1 2000-08-19   Chelsea    Arsenal                1                1       NaN
2 2000-08-23  Coventry   Man-City                3                0       NaN
3 2000-08-25  Man-City  Liverpool                1                1       3.0
4 2000-08-28     Derby   Man-City                1                1       NaN
5 2000-08-31     Leeds    Chelsea                3                0       NaN
6 2000-08-31  Man-City    Everton                3                0       1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm getting the following error: "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 7440 elements, new values have 7441 elements" (my original DataFrame has 7441 rows).

Comment: Emm. Are you trying the new version of the code or the original one? Also - which line produces the error? (and if you could share the data, I can try to run it on my side)

Comment: I'm trying the new version. The second line of code, i.e. groupby - transform, is causing the error. I'm struggling to figure out what exactly the issue is though... How can I share the data? Apologies, it's the first time I'm posting on stack overflow

Comment: Sharing the data - just upload to google drive or something similar and paste the link here. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I figured it out - your code works when using 'apply' instead of transform (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17093). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Your code works - thanks again for that! I'm struggling to understand it though, particularly the pd.merge_asof command. You're matching the 'AwayTeam' column in the right df with the 'HomeTeam' column in the left df - makes sense. Then you're merging on 'Date'. In the final merged df, for any merged row, the 'Date' of the 'roll_sum' would be different to what it was in the right df (i.e. 'away'). Is that why you are using pd.merge_asof (instead of pd.merge), to merge to the nearest date?

Comment: I'll add a couple of comments in the code. Let me know if it helps.